# Using ffmpeg with Python3 subprocess to convert multiple PNGs to a video

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am using Python3, subprocess and ffmpeg to convert multiple PNG images into a single video.

I have 400 PNG numbered as "00001.png".

This call for one single specific image to a a one-frame-video **works**:

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg","-y","-r","24","-i", "00300.png","-vcodec","mpeg4", "-qscale","5", "-r", "24", "video.mp4"])
```

However, when I try some methods seen online for calling all of my images formated as "#####.png" using "%05d.png" as below, **it does not work anymore**:

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg","-y","-r","24","-i", "%05d.png","-vcodec","mpeg4", "-qscale","5", "-r", "24", "video.mp4"])
```

I receive the error : `"%05d.png: No such file or directory"`.

I have the feelling that the above syntax is proper to Python2 and not working on my  python3 but can't find the correct python3 syntax anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: where did you see `"%05d.png"` ? On Linux may work `*.png` because `Bash` converts it to list of files with names matching `*.png`. I saw something like `"%05d.png"` only with image converter `ImageMagic`.

Comment: The ffmpeg syntax looks ok. Maybe it needs to be escaped in some way. @furas ffmpeg accepts that [syntax](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Examples-1) for image sequences.

Comment: I tried this `subprocess` and it worked for me. Because I had shorter names 001.png - 003.png in subfolder "test' so I used `"test/%03d.png"`. Do you run script in folder with images ?

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks. Could you please clarify the 'escaped' thing? I tried with a double %% but with no results...

Comment: @furas : Thanks. Do you use python3 or 2? I do run the script in the folder yes, and as you can see the above script works in the same folder for single image "00300.png", so not a directory issue... I'm lost

Comment: I use Python 3.5.2 on Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) and I updated `ffmpeg` to the newest 3.2.2

Comment: Well, this was the error on windows, but I just received the exact same one on my macBook now! Drives me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found the answer, and as expected it is disappointingly simple: The numbering has to start with 1 (00001 in my case), while in fact my files ranged from 00002.png to 00301.png.

Worked as soon as I added an initial 00001.png file.

Comment: Your Q claims otherwise :)  .   FFmpeg has a start_number option, so `"ffmpeg","-y","-r","24","-start_number","2","-i", "%05d.png"`

Comment: That's totally my mistake!  Thanks for the tip Mulvya.